# How to run a python script based on pip installation in docker?

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

My docker file design is as follows:

```
#Use python 3.6 image
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#install required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev python3-dev psmisc -y

#install a pip package
#Note: This pip package has a completely configured django project in it
RUN pip install <pip-packge>

#add a configuration file required for setup
ADD appAdd.json /

#Run a script
#Note: Here appmanage.py is a file inside the pip installed location, but it will be accesible directly without cd to the folder
RUN appmanage.py appAdd.json

#The <pip-packge> installed comes with a built in django package, so running it with following CMD
#Note: Here manage.py is present inside the pip package folder but it is accesible directly
CMD ["manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

When i run :

```
sudo docker build -t test-app .
```

The python script running part will be successful in terms of functionality but the image is not getting created because at this point it gets exited with following error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c appmanage.py appAdd.json' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

Is it treating it as shell script rather than python script. How can i overcome this and run the django project sucessfully?

Note: In local environment I could execute the steps in my machine and successfully setup.So no issues with the code of the django project which comes with pip package

## Update

The script appmanage.py runs the django project in a port 9999 and performs some tests and kills the port 9999. Is the kill operation in the script causing the error(137) as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full path to `appmanage.py`. To find that, you can use the site packages directory.

Replace

```
RUN appmanage.py appAdd.json
```

with

```
RUN PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES="$(python -c 'import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])')" \
    && python $PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES/<package>/appmanage.py
```

Comment: Yes i have tried that, this is the error : ```python3: can't open file 'appmanage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory ``` Because the file is located inside the pip package path(site-packages)

Comment: In that case, try using the full path to `appmanage.py`.

Comment: How can i get the pip path(where the package gets installed) ? Is there any environmental variable?

Comment: see my updated answer. what is the pip package you're installing?

Comment: Slightly modified the command so as to persist the value of the variable(edited your answer), But the problem is not solved, the script is getting executed but after the completion of the script, the build exits with the same error(137) as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have opened a new question regarding this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60126842/docker-the-command-returned-a-non-zero-code-137

Answer (score 0):

We can change the sh shell to python shell using run.

just modify the RUN part as follows:

```
RUN ["/bin/python", "appmanage.py", "appAdd.json"]
```

Comment: That does not help, please read the answer and comments of jakub

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer. Also that could be an answer for you but mine is another way of doing it. 
if you don't have the `/bin/python` please try '/bin/python3'. Also I have taken out the `-c` option as it was not required.