# Docker: The command returned a non-zero code: 137

Tags: python, django, docker, pip, dockerfile

My docker file is as follows:

```
#Use python 3.6 image
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#install required packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev python3-dev psmisc -y

#install a pip package
#Note: This pip package has a completely configured django project in it
RUN pip install <pip-package>

#Run a script
#Note: Here appmanage.py is a file inside the pip installed location(site-packages), but it will be accessible directly without cd to the folder
RUN appmanage.py appconfig appadd.json

#The <pip-packge> installed comes with a built in django package, so running it with following CMD
#Note: Here manage.py is present inside the pip package folder but it is accesible directly
CMD ["manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

When i run :

```
sudo docker build -t test-app .
```

The steps in dockerfile till: `RUN appmanage.py appconfig`  runs sucessfully as expected but after that i get the error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c appmanage.py appconfig ' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

When i google for the error i get suggestions like memory is not sufficient. But i have verified, the system(centos) is having enough memory.

## Additional info

The commandline output during the execution of `RUN appmanage.py appconfig` is :

```
Step 7/8 : RUN appmanage.py appconfig
 ---> Running in 23cffaacc81f

======================================================================================
configuring katana apps...
 Please do not quit (or) kill the server manually, wait until the server closes itself...!
======================================================================================
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 08, 2020 - 12:01:45
Django version 2.1.2, using settings 'katana.wui.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:9999/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
9999/tcp:
    20Killed
```

Comment: `wait until the server closes itself... ` --> it could be that when the server closes itself, it will return code 137? 1 way to check is to run the `appmanage.py appconfig appAdd.json` in your working environment, wait for the server to kill itself and print out the status code right after that: `echo $?`. As long as the return status code is !== 0, the `docker build` will fail.

Comment: I'm not making the server to quit. The script(appmanage.py) is the one which does that.I wont be able to customize the script since it belongs to pip package which im installing(observe the dockerfile). When i saw the source code of the script i found script is running ```os.system("fuser -k 9999/tcp")``` in order to kill the server

Comment: Yes, I know that the script(appmanage.py) is the one that makes the server to quit. And when that happens, it may return a non-zero status code which causes the `docker build` command to fail.

Comment: Yes, thanks for letting me know the actual cause of docker build fail, any idea to overcome this or a patch ?.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with this `appmanage.py appconfig appAdd.json`. Was it from another project that you just pull or copy over? Can you simplify it with a bash or python script instead of creating a server and kill it? Overall, just need to make sure that each `RUN` will exit successfully with code 0!

Comment: The purpose of the script is to install the django app inside the django project, Here is the source code of the script: https://github.com/warriorframework/warriorframework_py3/blob/master/katana/appmanage.py .

Comment: The script(appmanage.py) runs the django development server in order to check if the installed app is compatible or not, if it has any errors.

Comment: Ok, I see. Will try to build it myself when I have access to my computer next week!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described, the command `RUN appmanage.py appconfig appAdd.json` run successfully as expected and reported that `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`.

Moreover, the command "insisted" on killing itself and return exit code of 137. The minimum changes for this to work is to update your `Dockerfile` to be like

```
...
#Run a script
#Note: Here appmanage.py is a file inside the pip installed location(site-packages), but it will be accessible directly without cd to the folder
RUN appmanage.py appconfig appAdd.json || true
...
```

This will just forcefully ignore the return exit code from the previous command and carry on the build.